# Can't understand recursion

Tags: python, recursion

Please can someone explain why I can't get `True` as an answer. I got to the last action but it doesn't turn back.

```
a= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def isIn(char, aStr):
    mid_val = len(aStr) / 2
    if char == aStr[mid_val]:
        return True
    elif char < aStr[mid_val]:
        isIn(char, aStr[:mid_val])
    else:
        isIn(char, aStr[mid_val:])


print isIn('w',a)
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing your code to make more use of `mid_val` and to be more pythonic. You may want to review the changes for your enlightenment.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to return the results of the recursive function calls:

```
...
elif char < aStr[len(aStr)/2]:
    return isIn(char, aStr[0:mid_val])
else:
    return isIn(char, aStr[mid_val::])
...
```

Without this change, the return values of those two function calls will be ignored by Python and `isIn` will always return `None`, the default return value of functions.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you don´t need a function for that.

```
>>> print("a" in "abcdefgh")
True
```

Comment: i know how to resolve this other way, but this way i practice my recursion.